# Generating unique combinations in postgres of size two from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381237/how-to-get-an-array-in-postgres-where-the-array-size-is-greater-than-1) in which I generated arrays of this type of table:

```
 val | fkey | num
 ------------------
 1   |  1   | 10
 1   |  2   | 9  
 1   |  3   | 8  
 2   |  3   | 1
```

In which the resulting returned row would like something like this (fkeys were essentially aggregated to one list):

```
1 | [1,2,3]
```

What I would like to do is modify the query with respective to the value in the 'num' column. That is, I would like something like:

```
1 | [1,2] | [10, 9]
1 | [1,3] | [10, 8]
1 | [2,3] | [9, 8]
```

The ordering of the third column in the return query doesn't bother me. Right now I have something like this:

```
SELECT val, array_agg(fkey), array_agg(num)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY val
Having Count(fkey) > 1
```

But that returns something more like:

```
1 | [1,2,3] | [10, 9, 8]
```

Which would be ok, except I can't easily tell which number in the third array comes from what fkey (if that makese sense). Something like this would work to keep track of it:

```
1 | [1,2,3] | [10 - 1, 9 - 2, 8 - 3]
```

I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this is, but I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT: I'm on Postgres 9.3.6. The table definition is:

```
awesome-db=# \d mytable
Table "public.mytable"
Column    |  Type   | Modifiers 
----------+---------+-----------
 val      | bytea   | not null
 fkey     | uuid    | not null
 num      | integer | not null
 Indexes:
"comp_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (fkey, num, val)
"fingerprint_index" btree (val)
```

Comment: Two `array_agg()` calls in the same `SELECT` list take elements in the same order unless instructed otherwise with `ORDER BY` added to the function parameters. So you *can* tell which elements of the two arrays go together and your current function should do the job. What am I missing?

Comment: Generally, a question like this requires that you provide the table definition (`\d mytable` in psql) and your version of Postgres.

Comment: It is *much* better to copy / paste what you get from `\d mytable` in psql. Else we cannot be sure about the complete picture. For instance, I still don't know whether your columns are defined `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `self join` using `row_number`:

```
select t1.val,t1.fkey||','||t2.fkey,t1.num||','|| t2.num
from (select row_number() over(order by val) rn,
       val,
       fkey,
       num
from mytable) t1 
join (select row_number() over(order by val) rn,
       val,
       fkey,
       num
from mytable) t2
on t1.val=t2.val and t1.rn<t2.rn
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/92006/16)

Answer (score 1):

What you have does what you are asking for: the order of elements corresponds in both arrays.

Your first idea:

With a `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination `(val, fkey, num)` and `NOT NULL` constraints on all columns, you get arrays of two elements (smaller `(num, fkey)` first) like this:

```
SELECT t1.val
     , ARRAY[t1.num, t2.num] AS nums
     , ARRAY[t1.fkey, t2.fkey] AS fkeys
FROM   mytable t1 
JOIN   mytable t2 USING (val)
WHERE  (t1.num, t1.fkey) < (t2.num, t2.fkey);
```

Or your second idea:

```
SELECT val, array_agg(num) AS nums, array_agg(num::text || ' - ' || fkey) AS fkeys
FROM   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   mytable
   ORDER  BY num, fkey
   ) sub
GROUP  BY val
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57005/3)

Comment: I added some information - the unique constraint is between all three columns. It's possible to have a duplication of (val, fkey) in my definition.